# Bootstrap grip in mobile view and Desktop view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
      <img src="#"/>  
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <blockquote>
         <p style="font-size:20px; color:black;">"I had never seen anything in the least like them before. A single look at them is enough to show that they could only be written by a mathematician of the highest class. They must be true because, if they were not true, no one would have the imagination to invent them."</p>
         <footer><cite>Anonymous</cite></footer>
      </blockquote>
   </div>
</div>
```

Hi in the above code I am trying make the text and image side by side and I am getting the expected output while viewing in desktop but the same page when viewed in mobile I see part of text and image getting overlapped but the same page is ok when viewed in mobile in desktop view.

How would I sync the appearance in all view together?

Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks.

PS: I dont have enough reps to post the image so #'ing the img src value between quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This answer is for Bootstrap 4 only.

There are two issues with your code.

1. The image you're linking to is larger than the width of its container.
2. `*-xs-*` classes are removed.

#### Solutions

1. Add the [.img-fluid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/) class to make the image responsive.
2. Use the `col-8` and `col-4` classes instead of `col-xs-8` and `col-xs-4` respectively.

Since all your `breakpoints` are the same, it is enough to use `col-8` and `col-4` only. You should better remove the other `col-*-*` classes.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Augusta_National_Golf_Club%2C_Hole_10_%28Camellia%29_-_cropped.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <blockquote>
        <p style="font-size:20px; color:black;">"I had never seen anything in the least like them before. A single look at them is enough to show that they could only be written by a mathematician of the highest class. They must be true because, if they were not true, no one would have the
          imagination to invent them."</p>
        <footer><cite>Anonymous</cite></footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Run the **code snippet** or check this [pen on Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmEmVp)

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. I tried both your solutions.

I still see that when I view the page through my mobile I still see the image and the text(quote) overlaps with each other in potrait mode but does not overlap when I try to change it in landscape.

Also viewing the page checking the desktop site also is same as landscape.

How would I fix the issue the way it looks in potrait mode??

Thanks.

Comment: @Pandora-Box Which version of iOS or Andriod do you have?

Comment: Hi 
Mahan,

I use android 8.

Comment: Ok.  I just tested this on an `Andriod 8` phone. It works fine. Have opened your web page in Private mode(Incognito on Chrome)?

Comment: I tried in normal n private mode both yielded me the same result 

This is the page : https://codepen.io/premkrishnan/full/vjBROG/

Comment: @Pandora-Box. You have neither applied `img-fluid` to the image nor have used `col-*`  instead of `col-xs-*` classes. Fixed https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OZVXMV

Comment: I am missing something and now i face something very strange , I copy pasted your  code to my page and now i see image and quote in different lines when i view from computer.                                                              codepen.io/premkrishnan/full/vjBROG

Comment: You need to add Bootstrap version 4 in codepen. Check this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pVJEjZ

Comment: If it worked, you should accept the answer to help others also.

Answer (score 1):

### This answer is for Bootstrap 3 only.

Based on the above code I suspect your issue is that the `img` you're linking to is larger than the width of its container.  The easiest fix for that is to add a bit of responsive behavior to the image using Bootstrap's utility class `.img-responsive`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800" class="img-responsive" />  
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <blockquote>
        <p style="font-size:20px; color:black;">"I had never seen anything in the least like them before. A single look at them is enough to show that they could only be written by a mathematician of the highest class. They must be true because, if they were not true, no one would have the imagination to invent them."</p>
        <footer><cite>Anonymous</cite></footer>
      </blockquote>
   </div>
</div>
```

In the above code we have an 800px square image but the `imp-responsive` class always forces its `max-width` to 100% of its container.

One other change made to your code: You do not need to specify additional breakpoints if they are the same value.  Your `col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8` is the same as just using `col-xs-8`.

Comment: That day you answered one of my question that *the -xs- variant was removed in Bootstrap 4 everywhere*. I wonder if `col-xs-4` and `col-xs-8` are removed or not?

Comment: My apologies! I saw your use of `xs` and just assumed you were using Bootstrap 3.  Yes, `xs-*` is depreciated; just use `col-4` and `col-8`

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. I tried both your solutions.

I still see that when I view the page through my mobile I still see the image and the text(quote) overlaps with each other in potrait mode but does not overlap when I try to change it in landscape.

Also viewing the page checking the desktop site also is same as landscape.

How would I fix the issue the way it looks in potrait mode??

Thanks.